VS Code Auto-Complete with Control of Cursor Placement
I have a custom VS Code extension (which I cannot post) that handles syntax highlighting and auto-complete and I would like to add three additional auto-completes. The extension looks to have three files:

custom.Language-configuration.json
custom.snippets.json
syntaxes/custom.tmLanguage.json

The first will auto-complete if the user types the string ‘FOO’ follow by a space and then either an integer or a string enclosed in curly brackets. The auto-complete will add additional syntax and place the cursor after that space that follows the keyword ‘borg’. Here are several examples (the pipe denotes where the cursor should be placed but does not represent a pipe being added):
User types:
FOO 12
Auto-completes:
FOO 12
\tborg |
DONE

User Types:
FOO {something}
Auto-completes:
FOO {something}
\tborg |
DONE

The second is very similar to the first except we replace an integer or string in curly brackets with just a string, and the keyword ‘borg’ is no longer added. I want this to trigger off the string ‘BAR’; here is an example:
User Types:
BAR this_is_a_string
Auto-completes:
BAR this_is_a_string
\t|
DONE

Finally, if the user types ‘FIZZ’ with no following space, then it auto-completes to add DONE and place the cursor exactly like the previous.
User Types:
FIZZ
Auto-Completes:
FIZZ
\t|
DONE

I’ve tried doing this via the snippets file with the following:
{
    "FOO Completion": {
        "prefix": "FOO",
        "body": [
            "FOO ",
            "\tborg $0",
            "DONE"
        ],
        "description": "Auto-complete FOO with borg and DONE"
    }
}

the following is the relevant part of the language-configuration file (this already existed by the creator):
{
    "autoClosingPairs": [
        {"open": "FOO", "close": " \nDONE", "notIn": ["comment"]}
    ],
    "surroundingPairs" = [
        ["FOO", "\nDONE"]
    ]
}

and finally the relevant part of the syntaxes/tmLanguage file (this already existed by the creator):
{
        "section": {
            "patterns": [
                {
                    "name": "section.control.custom",
                    "begin": "\\bFOO\\b",
                    "end": "\\bDONE\\b",
                    "captures": {
                        "0": {
                            "name": "entity.name.type.foo.custom"
                        }
                    },
                    "patterns": [
                        {
                            "include": "#common"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "keyword.section.foo.custom",
                            "match": "(borg|bizz)"
                        }
                    ]
                },
}

I was not able to get this to work with the requirement on an integer or string in curly brackets. It was also inconsistent in so far as it’d work the first time (after typing the required syntax and hitting enter it would currently auto-complete), but then subsequent times after typing the required syntax and hitting enter all I’d be left with is just the syntax I had typed. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

try the extension Hypersnips
